# Double checking probability solution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A student has a quiz with 3 True/False and 2 Multiple Choice each with four answers. The student guesses on each one.

What is the probability that the student gets at least 3 correct. So we can find complement (I think this way is easier than the other in terms of thinking about it but I might be wrong).

So probability of none right is $.5^3*.75^2$. find probability that student is wrong on each account.

P(1): This one is a little confusing for me because either he gets a T/F right or a MC right. But in each case we get $.5^3*.75^2$ or $.5^3*.25*.75$. Is this the wrong way to think about this?

P(2): same as above but with more possibilities. 2 T/F right, 1 of each or 2 MC right.

Once I have found that simply do 1 minus what we found.

Lastly in order to find if he got all three T/F correct given he got at least 3 correct is .5^3/probability that we just found. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have $2^5=32$ different outcomes, with different probability depending on the specific distribution of correctness.

Let's describe an outcome as $(YYNNY)$ for instance, where the first three have probability of $Y$ of 0.5 and the 4th and 5th have probability of $Y$ of 0.25.

As you can see, there are exactly 16 outcomes where the student got at least three answers correct, and 16 where the student got at least three answers wrong (so at most two answers correct) so it does not help you to reverse the calculations.

Finally, let's make the calculations:

- All the $(YYY**)$ are good, we have $\frac{1}{2}^3$
- for the $(YYN**)$ and similar (there are three combinations), you need either one or two $Y$ on the right, so $3·\frac{1}{2}^3·(1-\frac{3}{4}^2)$
- Finally if you have only $(YNN**)$ (again, three combination depending on the position of $Y$) you need two $Y$ on the right, so $3·\frac{1}{2}^3·\frac{1}{4}^2$

So in the end you have $\frac{1}{2}^3(1+3(\frac{1}{4}^2 + 1-\frac{3}{4}^2)) = \frac{5}{16}$

Comment: how on earth did you get that equation from those answers?

Comment: Just take $\frac{1}{2}^3$ out as a common factor!